# Select * Where Column_A and Column_B Are Unique

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've got a table with about 70 million rows. I start by narrowing it down to about 250k rows by selecting from a specific sim_id.

Now, I need to select each first row that has a unique **combination** of sorted_hand AND ev. Put another way, I need to disregard all rows that duplicate an existing row's sorted_hand and ev and select what remains.

Table looks like this:

```
|| id || sim_id || sorted_hand || ev
|| 1 || 1 || 23AA || 2453
|| 2 || 1 || 23AA || 2453 
|| 3 || 1 || 23AA || 2453 
|| 4 || 1 || 2233 || -548 
|| 5 || 1 || 23AK || -296
|| 6 || 1 || 2233 || -548
```

In the example selection above, I would want the resulting query to select:

```
|| 1 || 1 || 23AA || 2453
|| 4 || 1 || 2233 || -548
|| 5 || 1 || 23AK || -296
```

All of the other rows are disregarded because they have the same exact ev and`sorted_hand as another row.

Comment: What is the question? You need a SQL statement or php code?

Comment: @davidev Whatever is the fastest. I'm currently doing it via PHP (looping through the hands and evaluating them manually based on the previous hand after sorting by ev and sorted_hand) and it's just too slow (takes about 3-4 seconds, need to be <1 second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the `min(id)` and just GROUP BY the rest of the columns to achieve this:

```
SELECT min(id) as id, sim_id, sorted_hand, ev FROM yourtable GROUP BY sim_id, sorted_hand, ev;
```

In essence, it's not so much "disregarding" but rather grouping records and just returning the first `id` encountered for that group.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the end `sorted_hand_ev`?

Comment: @Vladan Fixed the type. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to fit the bill perfectly, I'm spending at most .2 seconds fetching everything I need. For anyone else who comes across this though, my problem still persists because it appears my slow loading time has to do with rendering the large amount of rows in the browser, not actually fetching them.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.id = (
    select min(t1.id)
    from mytable t1
    where t1.sorted_hand = t.sorted_hand and t1.ev = t.ev
)
```

For performance, you want an index on `(sorted_hand, ev, id)`.

Alternatively, If you don't care about `sim`, or if it is acceptable to add it to the group, then you can  simply use aggregation

```
select min(id) id, sim, sorted_hand, ev
from mytable
group by sim, sorted_hand, ev
```